# Scraping Instagram Photos

Tags: import.io

Trying to do http://support.import.io/knowledgebase/articles/389408-infinite-scroll-without-prerender to scrape instagram photos but can't seem to find the URL.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it is understand how Instagram handles the infinite scroll. When you hit the bottom of the page, a new request is sent to the server.

This is a `POST` request to https://www.instagram.com/query/ passing the following structure as argument:

```
q:ig_me() {
  feed {
    media.after(1207458316004284237, 12) {
      nodes {
        id,
        caption,
        code,
        comments.last(4) {
          count,
          nodes {
            id,
            created_at,
            text,
            user {
              id,
              profile_pic_url,
              username
            }
          },
          page_info
        },
        date,
        dimensions {
          height,
          width
        },
        display_src,
        is_video,
        likes {
          count,
          nodes {
            user {
              id,
              profile_pic_url,
              username
            }
          },
          viewer_has_liked
        },
        location {
          id,
          has_public_page,
          name
        },
        owner {
          id,
          blocked_by_viewer,
          followed_by_viewer,
          full_name,
          has_blocked_viewer,
          is_private,
          profile_pic_url,
          requested_by_viewer,
          username
        },
        usertags {
          nodes {
            user {
              username
            },
            x,
            y
          }
        },
        video_url
      },
      page_info
    }
  },
  id,
  profile_pic_url,
  username
}
ref:feed::show
```

This piece of data `media.after(1207458316004284237, 12)` is actually what tells to the server what to return next and it is the identifier of the last post in the feed. It is basically telling "give me 12 new posts after the post with ID 1207458316004284237"